# jquery .focus not working for input:first

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are having an issue where when we open a modal window we are trying to set the focus to the first input element in the modal that is not of type hidden. here is what we are trying:

```
$("#test-overlay input[type!=hidden]:first").focus();
```

However, this call works:

```
$("#test-overlay #loginInput").focus();
```

The input field has an id of loginInput.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Simple proof of concept script on jsFiddle please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to the order of precedence in which jQuery interprets the selector. Try the following:

```
$('#test-overlay input').not('[type=hidden]').first().focus();
```

This has the added benefit of not using the `:first` and attribute not equal to selectors since they're jQuery specific and queries using these cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method.

Comment: This is working fine with firefox and chrome but not with IE. Any thoughts?

Comment: @NunuJ The above should be fine in IE. Is the code called when the document is ready?